# Get tag name of clicked element inside cross domain iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

The idea is simple: popup the tag name of the clicked element. The `Javascript` code:

```
function inspect(event) { alert(event.target.tagName); event.preventDefault(); }
```

Then, in the HTML:

```
<body onclick="inspect(event)">
```

The problem occurred when the clicked element is inside an cross domain `iframe`, for example the `iframe` source is Google.

So what's the solution here? I've tried a lot but it was unsuccessful. If you have any solution, or work around way, please help me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Not possible due to the [Same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript).

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Do you have any work around way? If I download that page and display it in my `iframe`, will that be possible to solve my problem?